# antlr is not recognized command

Tags: installation

I am receiving the error at command prompt that antlr is not recognized command.

I have downloaded `antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar` file, set it up on the system and configured the environment variables properly. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: “Set up the system and environment variables properly” - apparently not. Instead of requesting us to reiterate the same info already on the internet, tell us what directions you followed and WHAT “setup...properly” actually entailed.

Comment: And also which operating system.

Comment: windows 10 is the operating system

Comment: I have antlr.bat , class.bat and grun.bat created withe the code provided in antlr website. also downloaded the antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar file. I have set up the classpath environment variable which points to antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar file and I have added %classpath% and c:Javalib to the path environment variable. Under system variable, I have JDK location pointed in Path system variable. Not sure what else I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are doing wrong, as you have not shared any images, but anyways I would like to show how I could set it up, so that it could help someone else who might be stuck, like I was.

First of all, I hope you are using right command as `antlr4` and not just `antlr`

**Steps to set it up (on windows).**

**STEP 1:** Download the jar file from here https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.9-complete.jar and save it anywhere in your **C:/** drive, let's say under a folder named `antlr`, i.e., C:/antlr/ (my case I simply named the folder antlr, refer image below)

[image]

**STEP2:** Create a `.bat` file named `antlr4.bat` and put the following content in it.

```
java org.antlr.v4.Tool %*
```

(refer point 2 in above image I have kept the antlr.bat in the same folder as my jar, refer the image below to see the content of the bat file)

[image]

**Step 3:** Similarly create one more `.bat` file named `grun.bat` and put in the same folder as the jar with the content.

```
java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig %*
```

(refer the images)

**Step 4:** Now add the CLASSPATH variable in system variable, with value as the complete path to the jar file downloaded in step 1 above.
For my case it would be `C:\antlr\antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar` as I have put the downloaded jar file in C:/antlr.
Refer the image how my Classpath looks like
[image]

**Step 5:** I also added the path where I have put the .bat files added in STEP2 and 3 in the PATH system variable.
(refer image, how I added the path which is C:/antlr in my case where I have those bat files present)

[image]

Now , when I do antlr4 on command line it works (see image)

[image]

P.S. I got this article very helpful for the same, if you still could not get it right.
https://levlaz.org/setting-up-antlr4-on-windows/